# Validating number of arguments

Tags: bash

I apologize for the beginners question ahead of time but I cannot get this chunk of code to work properly. I was asked to make a basic program which asks the user for 3 numbers and then checks which is the highest value and prints the results, as well as makes sure there are three numbers put in. It can determine which is his highest and im getting it to output results properly but I cant seem to figure out how to get it to validate that there are three numbers put in.

I have done research and even pulled some code from the teachers example about how to check the number of arguments but I still cant get it to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter three numbers:"
read a b c
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
    then
    echo "You need three numbers"
    exit -1
fi
if [ $a -gt $b -a $a -gt $c ]
      then
              LARGEST=$a
elif [ $b -gt $a -a $b -gt $c ]
      then
              LARGEST=$b
elif [ $c -gt $a -a $c -gt $b ]
      then
              LARGEST=$c
elif [ $a -eq $b -a $a -eq $c -a $b -eq $c -eq $b ]
then
LARGEST="All three values are equal."
fi
echo "The largest values is $LARGEST"
```

When I enter three numbers (7 8 9) I expect to get back:
"The largest value is 9"

however I get this instead:

```
./values.sh: line 6 [0: command not found
The largest value is 9
```

Am i missing something blatantly obvious here? I know i need an operator to make my original if statement work but am i using the wrong one?

Comment: Line 6 in the code posted here is `then`. Please show your real code.

Comment: I think you didn't post your full code exactly verbatim as you're running it because the error message suggests you're missing a space after a `[` in an if or elif somewhere, and I don't see that anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that as well. I made an edit which shifted it back to how it actually. And to answer your other question I'm using BASH.

Comment: The edit still shows no [ on line 6. That isn't an accurate reproduction of your code.

Comment: ... who keeps upvoting this question? And why?

Comment: As you can see, I'm very new to this. I tried to make it is accurate is possible, but excuse my errors. My main question is to see if anyone has a way to check that the total number of arguments is 3 as that is what is tripping me up. I used: if [ $# -ne 3 ]  but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Number of arguments  **to the shell script itself** is $# -- that is not the number of items read by the `read`

Comment: Ah, I see. How would I check to see if the number of read items is three then? I'm taking this class online so it's hard to find someone to bounce this off of.

Comment: "*I used: if [ $# -ne 3 ]*" - No, that's not what you used. If you did, you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: You'd have to check if c is non-empty. Use `if [ -z $c ]`

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I bet that doesn't work.

Comment: I think somehow or other you're not posting the code you're actually running. But to save some hassle the problem is due to a missing space after a `[`. The thing about shell scripts traditionally is that `[` is not actually special syntax. After an `if` a command is normally taken and `if` evaluates on the return code of the command (the bash specific `[[]]` syntax is an exception here). In fact `[` is the name of a command, and is actually an alias for a command called `test`. The fact that it accepts a trailing `]` argument is for symmetry's sake.

Comment: It works . I just tested it in his code.

Comment: Point being you actually need a space after a `[` because it's the name of a command. If you do something like `z=0; if [$z ]; then` ... it will actually expand to `if [0`, where `[0` is most likely *not* the name of a real command.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Oh, I see. :-) It kind of works by accident.

Comment: Thank you @L.ScottJohnson  for your help, and Iguananaut as well. melpomene, I'm new to this and was very upfront about it, there's no need to be all snarky about it.

Comment: That and as already pointed out `$#` is for the number of arguments to the script. But even so you wouldn't get this specific error without missing a space, I don't think.

Comment: @PrestonDotsey Three people have told you that what you've posted here does not match the error message, and you're still refusing to fix your question. I don't get it. Why? And what does that have to do with being new?

Comment: I'm not refusing too, I just am not sure how to copy the file out of vim to post here (hence being new). Care to enlighten me? Every time I post on this website I get jumped on by people about improper formatting but I am trying and I try to make it clear that I know I'm being sloppy but I'm learning.

Comment: I knew that my issue in my first IF statement and I thought that would be picked up (which L.ScottJohnson did)

Comment: If you're using gvim or terminal vim with X clipboard integration, select the whole file (e.g. with `ggVG`) and copy it to the clipboard (`"+y`). Then you should be able to paste it in your browser (usually `Ctrl-V`).

Comment: Thank you, that will be useful to use in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[ -z "$c" ]` test solves it for the code you posted.
Working code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter three numbers:"
read a b c d
if [ -z "$c" ]
    then
    echo "You need three numbers"
    exit -1
fi
if [ -n "$d" ]
then
   echo "enter only three numbers"
   exit -1
fi
if [ $a -gt $b -a $a -gt $c ]
      then
              LARGEST=$a
elif [ $b -gt $a -a $b -gt $c ]
      then
              LARGEST=$b
elif [ $c -gt $a -a $c -gt $b ]
      then
              LARGEST=$c
elif [ $a -eq $b -a $a -eq $c -a $b -eq $c -eq $b ]
then
LARGEST="All three values are equal."
fi
echo "The largest values is $LARGEST"
```

Output:

```
$ ./t.sh
Please enter three numbers:
7 8
You need three numbers
$ ./t.sh
Please enter three numbers:
7 8 9
The largest values is 9
```

Comment: `[ -z $c ]` accidentally works for empty `$c` because it expands to `[ -z ]`, which tests whether `'-z'` is a non-empty string. But it fails pretty bad if `$c` contains multiple words. Try `7 8 9\ 10` as input.

Comment: Thank you, this did it. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @melpomene it works on design here. Checking the validity of the entries is another matter. The question was primarily about validating the count, not the content. Entering `x y z` would also fail.

Comment: No, `x y z` would only fail in the rest of the script, where it tries to use them as numbers. I'm specifically talking about the `[ -z $c ]` test.

Comment: Yeah -- it fails because of the space. Numbers don't have spaces.

Comment: Quotes added to handle that one case of malformed number input.

Comment: I just realized you don't even need `9\ 10`. If you enter `7 8 9 hello`, it also goes wrong. Your code only checks for too few arguments, but not too many.

Comment: Ah, yes. Need to throw a `d` in there to eat the trash.